# Find repeated objects in image

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a Quran book image, I want to find the verses ends in the image.

Examples:

[image]
[image]

Is there an idea for finding verses ends (which are in semi-circular shapes, containing an Arabic number inside them)?

**EDIT**

I need an algorithm with the following specs:

- input: an Uthmani Mushaf image (like above images)
- output: a list of points (x, y) denoting the verse-end-circle locations in the input image.

The verse-end-circles are in the lines of Quran itself, separating each verse from other. In the second image, we have at the center a Surah (chapter) separator, which is a very thick line containing the Surah name in Arabic (سورة النحل)

Comment: Please give more details.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have given it

Comment: I have tried using http://imagej.net/ imageJ with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform Hough-Transform http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/hough-circles.html plugin, but it not accurate (detecting some parts which are not verse ends and not detecting some real verse ends). I think it should be modified in some way to work fine with my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this open source project which solves the problem.

https://github.com/quran/ayah-detection